# CodeIgniter retrieve image from secret folder

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have create private folder in application folder: application/private/username, I'm uploading images here with ajax, that works, but how can I retrieve that image with ajax, and display it in img tag. First problem is that http://example.com/application/private/useraname/img.jpg is protected, I can't access it through out url in browser, how to display an image. Just advice, I wanna write code on my own.

This is part of function(that is part of controller) that grabs image:

```
 $filepath = 'path to image';
 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        if (file_exists($filepath)) {
            $img_handle = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath) or die("");
            echo $img_handle;
            ImageJpeg($img_handle);
 }
```

But how to get this image with ajax?

Comment: Rather than "getting it with ajax", I think you need to use javascript to create an <img> tag and set the src attribute to the url that gets the image.

Comment: @Samutz I do that on success with ajax, but it doesn't work.

Comment: And the url works if you go directly to it in your browser? Also, can you include your javascript in the question?

Comment: @Samutz Url doesn't work when I try to access it, I grab an image, and echo image with php, I need to grab that image on ajax success and display it.

Comment: Remove the echo and it should work. imagejpeg() outputs the image contents. In the code you posted, you're outputting $img_handle before the image contents, which will confuse the browser when it's trying to display an image.

Comment: @Samutz Hi, it works, how smart is to do this? to store image for a moment into memory?

Comment: It depends on how big your images are, how many you load at once, and how much RAM the server has. If memory becomes an issue, you might want to change the access to the folder that has the original images to load them from there instead.

Comment: @Samutz Great, thank you, just in case that I have to do that, can I still protected folder and images from direct access for users that are not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a PHP file that would get the filename eg `thumb.php?src=img.jpg` and inside that file, you load the image from that path and display it. This way the path of the images are not exposed to the user.